# citations using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, author-number

The following one is working for restricting maximum number of authors for both citations and bibliography but how do we restrict to only citations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxnames=2]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Filler text \parencite{bertram,companion,jaffe,moraux}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `maxnames` sets both `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames`.  If you want to have different threshholds, you need to set both.  The same goes for `minnames`, `mincitenames`, and `minbibnames`.  By default, `minnames` is set to 1 and `maxnames` is set to 3.